# Передать путь в одном параметре get через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Обращения к домену могут иметь случайный путь. По этой причине, требуется передавать все, что после хоста одним параметром. 
На примере выглядит так:

```
http://host.com/c/a/b/d/e/index.php
http://host.com/?path=c/a/b/d/e/index.php
```

Как решить задачу используя `RewriteRule`? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?path=$1
```

Первая строка нужна, чтобы избежать зацикливания